# Is there a way to make Tomcat start an app up as soon as the WAR has been deployed?

Tags: tomcat, servlets

My app has a bit of expensive setup to do when it first starts up.  It appears that as soon as I copy the WAR file in webapps, the log file says "Deploying web application archive Navaid.jar", but it doesn't actually run anything until I hit the URL.  I'd rather than have the first person to hit the url endure the wait time for this start up.  Is there an "onDeploy" method I could use or something to do that processing, or should I just have ant copy the file, wait a few seconds, and then wget the url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement a class with the `ServletContextListener` interface, then declare it as a listener in your web.xml:

```
<listener>
  <listener-class> ...your class here... </listener-class>
</listener>
```

Your class will get called on startup (& on shutdown).

Comment: Awesome, that works.  Now I just have to figure out how to get the other servlets to block responding until this is done, but that's another question.

Comment: No servlet will be invoked by the container until the call to your ServletContextListener is completed.  See http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a couple of Servlets to load on startup in your `web.xml` file. They can then call various parts of your app to make sure they are primed.